# Retrieving XMLs while parsing them

Tags: java, xml, parsing

While parsing an XML, given a Node object, can I retrieve the raw XML that corresponds to that Node? I'm using Java and parsing the XML using JDOM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Element.toString()` should return a String representation of the Element but 
you can also use the [XMLOutputter](http://www.jdom.org/docs/apidocs/org/jdom/output/XMLOutputter.html) for that purpose (for writing the xml to some outputstream):

```
Element e=document.getRootElement();
XmlOutputter outputter=new XmlOutputter();
outputter.output(e,System.out);
```

this simple snippet should write the XML of the root element to stdout.

hope that helped..

Comment: hmm thats what I wanted. Element.toString() won't work though. It returns [Element: <question/>] (question being my tag). XMLOutputter does the job. I used outputString(Element element) to get the raw XML as a String.